# E-mail Templates in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I need help with e-mail templates.  I have an html template with three embedded images in it.  I am using the restful authentication plugin and have tried to customize the default mailer.  The template works great as a standalone webpage but for some reason is not rendering properly with the images.  I can either get the images to attach but not render inline, or the don't attach at all.

**Anyway the mailer is as follows:**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def signup_notification(user)
    setup_email(user)
    @subject << 'Please activate your thredUP account'
    @body[:url] = "#{APP_CONFIG[:site_url]}/activate/#{user.activation_code}"
  end

  def activation(user)
    setup_email(user)
    @subject << 'Your account has been activated - Welcome to thredUP!'
    @url = APP_CONFIG[:site_url]
    @user = user
    content_type "text/html"  
    attachment :content_type => "image/gif",  :body => File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/email/bottom-border.gif")
    attachment :content_type => "image/gif",  :body => File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/email/top-border.gif")
    attachment :content_type => "image/png",  :body => File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/email/footer.png")
    attachment :content_type => "image/png",  :body => File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/images/email/logo-lid.png")
    render :layout => 'standard'
  end

  protected
    def setup_email(user)
      @recipients = "#{user.email}"
      @from = APP_CONFIG[:admin_email]
      @subject = "[#{APP_CONFIG[:site_name]}] "
      @sent_on = Time.now
      @body[:user] = user
    end
end
```

**I have also built the template as follows:**

```
<html>
<body leftmargin="0" marginwidth="0" topmargin="0" marginheight="0" offset="0" bgcolor='#EFEFEF' >
<table width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="40" border="0" class="backgroundTable" bgcolor='#EFEFEF' >
    <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="center">
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding-bottom:15px;"><img src="cid:logo-lid.png">   </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="cid:top-border.gif"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr  bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                    <td style="padding:20px;">
                        <%= yield %>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><img src="cid:bottom-border.gif"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align:center; padding-top:15px;">
                        <img src="cid:footer.png">
                    </td>
                </tr>   
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is there any particular reason that they need to be attached rather than hosted on your server and then referenced in the email (e.g. `<img src="http://your.server/image.png" />`)?

I would imagine that that would simplify it.

Comment: ok I will try that.  I guess I remember back in my windows days, having to approve the download of server side images.  I assume this has changed?

Comment: I can't speak for every client, but that is how most newsletter services seem to handle it, and it works.

Comment: Many clients block hosted images by default [for good reasons], but most allow inline (attached) images.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on attaching them, try using Jason King's inline_attachment gem. Works best for static images.

Link: http://github.com/JasonKing/inline_attachment/tree/master

Comment: links broken, consider deleting answer